# Automatisation&Piping of diverse tasks

Tags: scripting, automation, build-system

I am looking for recommendations for a very generic automation/task execution tool. The scope is somewhat between a script, a build system like make and orchestration tools like Ansible or Puppet. The best I can do is describe my rather vague 'requirements' and hope for clues how others have solved these problems. Sorry for the long description, I guess I don't really know what exactly I want he solution to do. I profit from programming answers on SO all the time but I am not entirely sure if my open ended question is acceptable here.

--
We work as data analysts/system validators in a corporate setting. We perform a range of diverse tasks and interact with lots of ever changing systems. Each little step we do is arguably mundane/easy, but the bigger picture only forms if lots of iterations with slightly different inputs or combinations are repeated. It is a bit like looking for a needle in a hay stack, but the concrete problem is slightly different every time. This makes it hard to use a normal script or automation tool, which require more structure to work. But doing things semi-manual without a big team does not allow us to cover all the analysis/cases we want/need.

To give an applied example: a typical tasks could involve setting up a big calculation in a vendor system, extracting their ASCII output from a web server and parsing it. Then we would suck raw input data from a set of configuration files and data bases. This is piped into some of our home grown replication tools/models living in C++. Then both the system's results and our replication is scanned for interesting outliers (e.g. regression tested) and only this subset is uploaded for human analysts to investigate, nicely presented in an Excel sheet.

We can do all these things easily by hand for a once-off or maybe using ad-hoc tools/scripts. We just can't do it repeatedly for ever so slightly different settings. We seem to need a library for 'common tasks' that are just specialized by some few inputs (e.g. task it to download a time series and scan for outliers - parameters would be db access/login and maybe parameters defining what an outlier is in that context). And then I need to chain these tasks together to make complex tasks repeatable and simple to build up from atomic steps.

I have not found anything really do something like this. There seems to be specialist scripting or tools for each niche available, but not something combining all the different tasks I need to perform.

I have been so far toying on and off with a minimalist sqlite database which controls a set of python 'scripts'/wrappers. These scripts take input parameters from the data base, and they are chained/piped based on the database. The scripts write their results back to the database, mostly as plain text and floats/ints. This kind of db interface is very error prone and complicated for humans; the idea is to have (template) scripts writing (concrete/parametrised) scripts to the db for execution, like rolling itself out before executing. Not sure if this is a smart idea, but the db is driving the scripts, without much interacting among these building block script; rather than having the conventional bunch of scripts calling each other and dumping some data into db as an after thought. So far we have lots of separate wrappers (scripts) to talk to all the systems and do the work, what is really missing is something tying it all together an controlling it.

I am interested (obviously) more in data/flow transparency, repeatability and chaining mini-programs together to bigger units, rather than speed or scaling to larger data sets. All the heavier lifting is either done in the systems we interact with, or it is delegated to C++ called from these python scripts. This is not a production system with more stability and fixed goals but rather a flexible analysis/investigation helper.

I really hope someone here has previously run into exactly that problem severely limiting our productivity, and we can just piggy back off your solution or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you consider [staf](/questions/tagged/staf) ([Software Test Automation Framework](http://staf.sourceforge.net/)).  It's open source, distributed, and cross-platform. It will run just about any task on just about any platform.  It has a variety of plugin "Services" available for specific purposes, or you can create your own custom Service.  You can also extend the functionality through scripting ([jython](/questions/tagged/jython)) It's also well documented and reasonably well supported through user forums by IBM.